# SuiteBar Branding Element disappeared

Tags: branding

somehow my branding elemnt disappeared.
If I try to get it from Powershell it is still there

```
PS C:\temp> $app = Get-SPWebApplication http://myintranet
PS C:\temp> Write-Host $app.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml
<div class=ms-core-brandingText>MyIntranet</div>
PS C:\temp> Write-Host $app.Name
MyIntranet
```

But it doesn't show up on the site? It's not hidden by css.
Do you know what could be the problem or how to solve it?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
This is what is rendered:

```
<div id="suiteBarLeft">
<div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
    <div class="ms-tableRow">
            <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">

                </div>
```

While a working site collection has the following code:

```
<div id="suiteBarLeft">
    <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
    <div class="ms-tableRow">
        <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">
            <div class="ms-core-brandingText">SharePoint</div>

                </div>
```

I am using a custom master page but not a custom solution. Going back to a seattle masterpage doesn't solve.

Comment: not a good solution but I've forced the text with jquery

Comment: Does there exist something like an official solution to this issue? I am struggling with exactly the same problem and don't know where to search anymore.
When creating a new site collection on the same server with the same design, it works properly. Shouldn't in the master-file exist a line, which integrates the SuteBarBrandingElementHtml or something like that? Regards,
Eddie

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this (that's better than using JavaScript) is to create a user control that inherits and deploy it as a delegate control in a feature.

Tobias Zimmergren wrote an article about the different new delegates in SP 2013 that can help you override the left or the right side of the SuiteLinks bar:

[SP 2013: Some new DelegateControl additions to the SharePoint 2013 master pages](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing " around the class attribute. This probably makes your browser a bit angry.

Try to set it like:

```
<div class="ms-core-brandingText">MyIntranet</div>
```

and then do an `$app.Update()`

Comment: It doesn't wotrk. I have also simply tried : $webapp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "MyIntranet" but no luck

Comment: Does it get rendered at all? And do you have any custom solutions installed? Could be something overriding the whole SuiteBar element

Comment: It' doesn't get rendered at all. I've edited with what is rendered. I'm not using a custom solution

Answer (score 0):

For resolving your issue , you need to activate this feature:

```
Go to CA

Click System Settings->Manage farm features under Farm Management

Scroll to the feature 'Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls', activate it
```

[original post is here under "update"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146983/where-is-the-control-that-renders-the-suitebar)