# Where is the control that renders the SuiteBar?

Tags: 2013

I just moved from SP2010 to SP2013 and restarting my branding. The first thing I wanted to change was the SharePoint text in the top left corner, the suite bar.

Now I did find I could change it using powershell, jquery and a bunch of other methods but where does the text come from? When I Google it, I see people talking about a "`SuiteBarBrandingDelegate"` delegate control, however I cannot find it. It's not used in the master page and it's not in the 15 hive. Can anyone explain to me which control is responsible for rendering this text?

Comment: have you checked this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/findnavish/archive/2013/02/07/sharepoint-2013-customizing-suite-bar.aspx

Comment: http://www.proactivespeaks.com/2013/10/03/966/

Comment: Neither of these posts explain where the text comes from. As stated, I know how to change it using all the mentioned methods. But e.g. if I see a blog post explaining it's a delegate control, then I expect a delegate control with that name in the masterpage file. However the delegate control is not in my masterpage file. So how does it get rendered? What and where is the code/control/script/... that calls something to get the text rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text "SharePoint" on top of the SharePoint 2013 suite bar is ootb and can be changed through CSS, PowerShell or a delegate control.

The delegate control responsible is `SuiteBarBrandingDelegate` and should be included in the master page as follows (copied from seattle.master):

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" ControlId="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" runat="server"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .ms-core-brandingText:after{ content:"Powered by Rackspace"; }

 .ms-core-brandingText{ margin-left: -95px; }
```

**PowerShell:**

```
 $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://tozit-sp:2015

 $webApp.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = "<div
 class='ms-core-brandingText'>YOUR branded name HERE</div>"

 $webApp.Update()
```

**Delegate Control:**

elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <!-- SuiteBarBrandingDelegate (the top-left "SharePoint" text on a page) -->
  <Control ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/15/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/SuiteBarBrandingDelegate.ascx"
           Id="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate"
           Sequence="1" />

</Elements>
```

**.ascx**

```
<div class="ms-core-brandingText" id="BrandingTextControl" runat="server" />
```

**.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BrandingTextControl.Controls.Add(new Literal
    {
        Text = "your custom text here"
    });
}
```

Sources

http://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-sharepoint-branding-text-in-the-upper-left-part-of-your-screen

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-tip-change-the-sharepoint-text-in-the-top-left-corner

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/55a3575a-8d22-427d-90d4-604cd0a4a702/how-to-change-sp-2013-sharepoint-mscorebrandingtext-div

and finally, delegate control method implementation explained,

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages

**Update:**

The farm feature 'Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls' adds the suite bar branding control to the master page, so if this feature is disabled, the suite bar branding HTML will not be shown.

For resolving your issue , you need to activate this feature:

1. Go to CA
2. Click System Settings->Manage farm features under Farm Management
3. Scroll to the feature 'Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls', activate it

Comment: Hi Tiago, thanks for your response. As stated above, I know how to change the text but where does it come from. Which control/code on the masterpage is responsible for rendering this text (ootb)? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: answer updated!

Comment: Thanks Tiago, That's exactly what i was looking for. For those who are interested, it's this control: <PublishingRibbon:PublishingRibbon runat="server"/>.
BTW, I find this a realy strange place to put branding, in the social tags and note board, go figure...

Comment: Thank you for this information about missing feature..